# In php shell php version wrong

Tags: php

I use hosting and in my setting php version is 7.4.16. but if i use [phpshell](https://phpshell.sourceforge.io/) and check version with php -v output is:

> PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Apr  1 2020 04:07:17)

why?
I can not use phpshell?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Many providers have diffrent versions of php installed, try php72, php73 or ask your provider what the settings are. You may have to provide the full path to the php executable like:

```
/usr/bin/php-7.4/php -v
```